# How to get top level billing items for an invoice

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I use the following API to get top level billing items for current month

```
https://{{sluser}}:{{slkey}}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems.json
```

I want to fetch same data for previous month.

Here is what I have tried. Get last month's invoice id and query it to get top level billing items:

```
https://{{sluser}}:{{slkey}}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice/8116829/getInvoiceTopLevelItems.json
```

But this gives me softlayer invoice items and not billing items. Then I tried:

```
https://{{sluser}}:{{slkey}}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice/8116829/getObject.json?objectMask=mask[createDate,invoiceTopLevelItems[billingItem[id]]]
```

Though this gives me softlayer billing items but they are not top level billing items. I get many billing items with same billing_item_id. I want to get top level billing items from an invoice. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
https://{{sluser}}:{{slkey}}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice/8116829/getObject.json?objectMask=mask[invoiceTopLevelItems[id,resourceTableId,billingItem[id,hostName,createDate,orderItem[id,order[userRecord[id,username]]],category[group]]]]
```

This API worked for me :)